# how to get data from two different table from wordpress database

Tags: php, wp-query, mysql

I have two different table in **wordpress** one is custom table and another is `wp_usermeta` table.

one `email` is matched from both table so i want to get data from both table using email address is matched. My query is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta,tbl_information 
WHERE   wp_usermeta.meta_value = 
tbl_information.account_email AND 
((wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'mycv') OR (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'drivinglicence') OR 
(wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name') OR (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'last_name') OR 
(wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'address') OR (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'nickname'))"

$infos = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

foreach ($infos as $u) {
      $users[$a->user_id][$a->meta_key] = $a->meta_value;
}
foreach ($users as $u) {
   <?php echo $u['first_name'].' '.$u['last_name'];?>
}
```

This is works but when i try to print tbl_information table data like one of the field is: `account_name`

So i try to print like `<?php echo $u['account_name'];?>`

But it wont work.

Comment: did you try a var_dump on $u

Comment: yes i got all details on their. but not print it

Comment: try updating the question with the result of var_dump above